# File relative to jar using Spring

Tags: java, spring, file

I work on a Java console application. There is a property in my application.properties file, which contains another file name as a value of a property, like

```
my.file.location=file:myDir/myFileName
```

In the code I try to get the file like this:

```
@Value("${my.file.location}")
private File myfileLocation;
```

If I start the application from the directory, which contains jar file, the file is resolved, but when I run my application from a different location, the file location is not valid.

I can't have this file on classpath, it must be external to the jar file.

How can I make the file path to be relative to my jar file and not to the current working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has nothing to do with Spring right? You just want to load configuration file, that is inside your application, unpacked, so the user can modify it, ok?

**First**, you may try to always setup the **working directory**, which I believe is more *"standard"* solution. In windows you can make a *link*, that specifies the *Start in* section and contains the path to your `jar` file (or `bat` or `cmd`, whatever).

If you insist on using the **jar path**, you could use [How to get the path of a running JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file) solution. Note, that the jar must be loaded from filesystem:

```
URI path = MySpringBean.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
File myfileLocation = new File(new File(path).getParent(), "/myDir/jdbc.properties");
```

Comment: Thank you for provided answer. I was wondering, how to use the @Value("${my.file.location}") relative to the jar file, so this question is really related to Spring.

Comment: Well, you can call `myfileLocation.getPath()` to get the relative path, but than you still have to create new `File` with the full path. You could do this completely using spring [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), if you need it.